# How do I sum up two fields in the Mongoshell?

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a find statement in a store database that looks like this:

```
db.Purchases.find( {}, { store: 1, total: 1, _id: 0 } ).sort( { "store" : 1} ) =

{ "store" : DBRef("Location", ObjectId("5dae22702486f7d89ba7633c")), "total" : "$1500" }
{ "store" : DBRef("Location", ObjectId("5dae227f2486f7d89ba7633d")), "total" : "$156.88" }
{ "store" : DBRef("Location", ObjectId("5dae22992486f7d89ba7633e")), "total" : "$1510" }
{ "store" : DBRef("Location", ObjectId("5dae22992486f7d89ba7633e")), "total" : "$3000" }
{ "store" : DBRef("Location", ObjectId("5dae22cd2486f7d89ba76340")), "total" : "$156.88" }
```

I need to sum the totals from output 3 and 4 (i.e $1510 and $3000) and display the result as one line in the output along all the other outputs. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.Purchases.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$store",
           totalAmount: { $sum: "$total"}
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

**Observation**: total must be a numeric type in MongoDB.